# How retrieve SQL query result to show in grid view header? ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I have table in SQL Server - here's a screen shot is

[LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bypjG.png).

I have `SqlCommand` which retrieves columns from the table, and I want to show these column in a gridview. Also, I want to insert a textbox in every gridview header and an `INSERT` button in the gridview row.

When the user inserts values and presses `INSERT` then new row is generated and same user again insert same like we insert data in table.I want to generate `textbox` dynamically according to gridview columns. Columns may be 1, 2 or 10. It depends on the user table.

ASPX markup:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="title" Runat="Server">
    <title>Insert Data</title>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" Runat="Server">
    <form id="form" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="load" Text="Button" />
    </form>
</asp:Content>
```

Code behind:

```
public void load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //string tbl_name = Session["value"].ToString();
    //string tbl_name = "new";
    string query = "USE db_compiler SELECT Column_Name FROM tbl_field WHERE Table_Name='pak'";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnn);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    cnn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    adp.Fill(dt);

    for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
         table.Columns.Add(Convert.ToString(i));
    }

    DataRow dr;

    //get all the columns and make it as rows
    for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        dr = table.NewRow();
        dr[0] = dt.Columns[j].ToString();

        for (int k = 1; k <= dt.Rows.Count; k++)
            dr[k] = dt.Rows[k - 1][j];

        table.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    GridView1.DataSource = table;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    cnn.Close();
}
```

I want `name`,`id` ,`city` shown in `GRIDVIEW` header and in every `GRIDVIEW` column dynamically generate `textbox` according to `header` and at the end `INSERT` button.

Thanks

Comment: You need to add those fields to your SQL query.  SELECT name, id ,city FROM tbl_field WHERE Table_Name='pak'

Comment: But here is 3 columns.We can't reterive query on the basis of columns because we don't know how much column user will create